# IBM IMS connection on Tomcat using JNDI - JAVA

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi, ims-db

We are in process of migration from WAS8 to Tomcat8. In Tomcat, we need to establish connection using JNDI for IMS in Java..

I am facing problem to create "URL" for JNDI connection of IBM IMS, below is the url struture given by IBM IMS JDBC jar

for driverType 4    **"jdbc:ims://datastoreServer[:port]/databaseName[:property=value;]";**

for driverType 2 **"jdbc:ims:databaseName[:property=value;]";**

This is what i have created

```
jdbc:ims://xx.xx.xxx.com:4034;datastoreName=XXX34;dpsbOnCommit=true;
```

but it is given me error during connection

```
Dec 07, 2017 12:55:30 PM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid URL syntax: databaseName not specified properly. Correct syntax: jdbc:ims://datastoreServer[:port]/databaseName[:property=value;]
    at com.ibm.ims.jdbc.IMSDriver.parseOptionalPortNumber(IMSDriver.java:1031)
    at com.ibm.ims.jdbc.IMSDriver.connect(IMSDriver.java:211)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:307)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:708)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:642)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:464)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:141)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:115)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:102)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:553)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:241)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:94)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:841)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:152)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:829)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:152)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:829)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:152)
```

above problem looks solved by correct url param but now i am getting error

```
java.sql.SQLException: An error occurred reading from the socket input stream: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed.
    at com.ibm.ims.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.init(ConnectionImpl.java:309)
    at com.ibm.ims.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:95)
    at com.ibm.ims.jdbc.IMSDriver.connect(IMSDriver.java:450)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:307)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:708)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:642)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:464)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:141)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:115)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:102)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:553)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:241)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:94)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:841)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:152)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:829)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1084)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:663)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.ibm.ims.drda.base.DisconnectException: An error occurred reading from the socket input stream: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed.
    at com.ibm.ims.drda.t4.Reply.fill(Reply.java:801)
    at com.ibm.ims.drda.t4.Reply.ensureALayerDataInBuffer(Reply.java:752)
    at com.ibm.ims.drda.t4.Reply.readDssHeader(Reply.java:937)
    at com.ibm.ims.drda.t4.Reply.startSameIdChainParse(Reply.java:132)
    at com.ibm.ims.drda.t4.T4ConnectionReply.readExchangeServerAttributes(T4ConnectionReply.java:710)
    at com.ibm.ims.drda.t4.T4Connection.readServerAttributesAndKeyExchange(T4Connection.java:283)
    at com.ibm.ims.drda.t4.T4Connection.flowServerAttributesAndKeyExchange(T4Connection.java:263)
    at com.ibm.ims.drda.t4.T4Connection.flowDRDAConnect(T4Connection.java:248)
    at com.ibm.ims.drda.t4.T4Connection.flowConnect(T4Connection.java:231)
    at com.ibm.ims.drda.t4.T4Connection.initialize(T4Connection.java:218)
    at com.ibm.ims.drda.t4.T4Connection.<init>(T4Connection.java:84)
    at com.ibm.ims.drda.db.DRDAEngine.establishAuthenticatedSocketConnection(DRDAEngine.java:205)
    at com.ibm.ims.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.init(ConnectionImpl.java:258)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ims.drda.t4.Reply.fill(Reply.java:796)
    ... 43 more
```

Comment: please provide me extact url if any one know....

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: You use the type 4 syntax that is expecting the database name following the port separated with a slash `/` - but there is neither a slash nor a database name in your URL.

Comment: yes i have update it

jdbc:ims://xxx.xx.com:4034/class://com.xx.xx.xx.application.S2U1LPSJDatabaseView:datastoreName=xx34;dpsbOnCommit=true;


after doing this connection i think not giving any error but due / in between on URL the tomcat is not getting start and hanging...

this is inside my context.xml and due to / tomcat stucking....any idea how to overcome

Answer (score 0):

For the Type-4 connection url:

```
jdbc:ims://datastoreServer[:port]/databaseName[:property=value;]
```

The databaseName placeholder should be replaced with your **PSB name** if you're using the IMS catalog

or with

```
class://your.fully.qualified.PSBNameDatabaseView
```

if you're using a local metadata file